# How to trigger a button automatically that is within an embedded site?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a twitter timeline embedded on my site and I want it to automatically scroll to the bottom of my timeline. Auto scroll is working, but the embedded version of twitter has a "Load More Button" that needs to be activated in order for the timeline to scroll any further down.

[image: Here is what I have tried so far]

Some other things I have tried are getting the class name using the google developer tools, but that doesn't seem to work either. I am not sure if I can actually access those because those classes are not directly stated in my HTML file. Currently I am thinking that I need to first get the class name of the embedded timeline, then from there in the same function access the load more button HTML class.

Comment: Please **do not** post screenshots of code. Use code tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the twitter timeline is embedded in an `iframe`, calling the global `document` object refers to the main DOM, but the nested `iframe` has its own. Just use `window.frames["nested-frame-name"].document` instead.

Using your code example you should correct

```
var loadMoreButton = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline");
```

into

```
var loadMoreButton = frames["twitter-frame-name"].document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline");
```